# Discord bot is joining voice channel and throws an error when trying to play music, saying it is not in voice channel

Tags: python, discord, discord.py, youtube-dl

Currently attempting to write a discord bot out of boredom.

The issue is when I try to run it, it goes into the voice channel, and when I request it to play a song, it throws an error in VSCode saying "Ignoring exception in command join"
Here is the code I have:

```
import asyncio
import os
import random
import discord
import json
import random
import yt_dlp as youtube_dl
from dotenv import load_dotenv
from discord.ext import commands
from discord.ext import tasks
from discord.ext.commands import has_permissions, MissingPermissions
from discord.utils import get
from itertools import cycle

intents = discord.Intents.all()
client = discord.Client(intents=intents)
bot = commands.Bot(command_prefix='!',intents=intents)

youtube_dl.utils.bug_reports_message = lambda: ''

ytdl_format_options = {
    'format': 'bestaudio/best',
    'restrictfilenames': True,
    'noplaylist': True,
    'nocheckcertificate': True,
    'ignoreerrors': False,
    'logtostderr': False,
    'quiet': True,
    'no_warnings': True,
    'default_search': 'auto',
    'source_address': '0.0.0.0' # bind to ipv4 since ipv6 addresses cause issues sometimes
}

ffmpeg_options = {
    'options': '-vn'
}

ytdl = youtube_dl.YoutubeDL(ytdl_format_options)

class YTDLSource(discord.PCMVolumeTransformer):
    def __init__(self, source, *, data, volume=0.5):
        super().__init__(source, volume)
        self.data = data
        self.title = data.get('title')
        self.url = ""

    @classmethod
    async def from_url(cls, url, *, loop=None, stream=False):
        loop = loop or asyncio.get_event_loop()
        data = await loop.run_in_executor(None, lambda: ytdl.extract_info(url, download=not stream))
        if 'entries' in data:
            # take first item from a playlist
            data = data['entries'][0]
        filename = data['title'] if stream else ytdl.prepare_filename(data)
        return filename
    
@bot.event
async def on_ready():
    print("The Bot is Ready!")
    
@bot.command(name='join', help='Tells the bot to join the voice channel')
async def join(ctx):
    if not ctx.message.author.voice:
        await ctx.send("{} is not connected to a voice channel".format(ctx.message.author.name))
        return
    else:
        channel = ctx.message.author.voice.channel
    await channel.connect()

@bot.command(name='leave', help='To make the bot leave the voice channel')
async def leave(ctx):
    voice_client = ctx.message.guild.voice_client
    if voice_client.is_connected():
        await voice_client.disconnect()
    else:
        await ctx.send("The bot is not connected to a voice channel.")

@bot.command(name='play', help='To play song')
async def play(ctx,url):
    try :
        server = ctx.message.guild
        voice_channel = server.voice_client
        async with ctx.typing():
            filename = await YTDLSource.from_url(url, loop=bot.loop)
            voice_channel.play(discord.FFmpegPCMAudio(executable="C:\ffmpeg\ffmpeg-master-latest-win64-gpl\bin\ffmpeg.exe", source=filename))
        await ctx.send('**Now playing:** {}'.format(filename))
    except:
        await ctx.send("The bot is not connected to a voice channel.")


@bot.command(name='pause', help='This command pauses the song')
async def pause(ctx):
    voice_client = ctx.message.guild.voice_client
    if voice_client.is_playing():
        await voice_client.pause()
    else:
        await ctx.send("The bot is not playing anything at the moment.")
    
@bot.command(name='resume', help='Resumes the song')
async def resume(ctx):
    voice_client = ctx.message.guild.voice_client
    if voice_client.is_paused():
        await voice_client.resume()
    else:
        await ctx.send("The bot was not playing anything before this. Use play_song command")

@bot.command(name='stop', help='Stops the song')
async def stop(ctx):
    voice_client = ctx.message.guild.voice_client
    if voice_client.is_playing():
        await voice_client.stop()
    else:
        await ctx.send("The bot is not playing anything at the moment.")
        
if __name__ == "__main__" :
    bot.run('token')
```

I have ffmpeg in correctly, I have the latest versions of yt_dlp, youtube_dl, PyNaCl, Discord.py, and discord.py[voice] all installed.
the token has been removed for the purposes of posting

Ive tried changing the path locations, but honestly at this point im more at a loss than anything else. Im new to coding so its more confusing than not.

Answer (score -1):

Make sure that the path of the FFMPEG executable file is correct and that the module is installed. Instead of typing the path directly as a string, try the `os.path.join` function

Also check in the debugger what `discord.FFmpegPCMAudio(executable="C:\ffmpeg\ffmpeg-master-latest-win64-gpl\bin\ffmpeg.exe", source=filename)` returns and what type should correctly accept `voice_channel.play` in documentation or your debugger.

Here you have more information on how to properly install FFmpeg:
https://github.com/adaptlearning/adapt_authoring/wiki/Installing-FFmpeg